# Stripped Electrical Outlet Box

Tags: screws

[image]

An electrical box's screw hole is stripped (annotated in red).  These screws pin the cover in place.   I can replace the box, however, I was wondering if there is clever technique that can overcome the problem.

I suspect that it may easiest to replace the box, however, if I am wrong, then it makes sense to ask the question:  Other than replacing the box, how does one overcome the problem of a stripped hole?

Comment: are you asking about the grounding screw?

Comment: Good question: No, the screws that hold the cover plate in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is an 8-32 screw.

You can obtain a 10-32 screw, including varieties which self-tap.

The thread pitch must be -32 or finer (which in practice means -32).  This is necessary for ground to be passed through the screw threads, if you are using the mounting screws to carry ground.

All "green ground screws" intended for metal boxes are 10-32, and some self-tap.

Comment: Ordered the [Klein tap screwdriver](https://www.kleintools.com/videos/how-use-multi-bit-tap-tool):  looking forward to trying your suggestion

Comment: Damn, that's a stepped 6-32, 8-32 and 10-32 tap.  I had no idea that existed, I just use hardware store taps intended for general purpose metal work. That's cool though. Takes advantage of how all electrical screws are -32 pitch.

Comment: I thought it would please you that the Klein tap was a fast / effective fix.  Credit awarded.

Answer (score 8):

Harper's answer is certainly correct and doable, but if you're in a remote area (or something) and can't get to a store that sells 10-32 screws, there's another trick that works. And -- side note -- it's especially useful on breaker panels with stripped holes for the cover that use those double-threaded screws.

1. Support the tab that has the stripped hole using a block of wood or some other convenient object.
2. Using a center punch, a nail set or a small flat-faced drift and a hammer, nick or dent the steel in a circular pattern around and very close to the stripped hole. For example, make a pattern of six or eight marks around the hole. No need for extreme hammer blows -- a gentle dent works fine.
3. The hole is now smaller. Remove the block of wood and carefully start the screw in the hole, being careful not to cross-thread. Screw the screw all the way down, then remove it.
4. You now have a repaired, tapped hole.

When I moved into my current house, five of the six the breaker panel screw holes were stripped. I used this method and now they're good as new.

Comment: Very good idea! More +1's would be given if I could. Going to remember this...

Comment: Innovative!  If only the hole was not in an unsupported tiny tab.

Comment: @gatorback You can support the tab with a block of wood inside the box. I've also used a random piece of steel to back up a tab. A piece with enough weight, held there by hand, allows inertia alone to provide enough support to let the impact tool dink the tab.

Answer (score 4):

Just find the “next” size up self taper and screw it in.